# Should I use an interface, inheritance or just add more logic to base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a program where the user creates a list of Child objects.
After they have added all the children they can click on the child and decide if that child is naughty and if so create a list  who they can't sit with.

Should I add a boolean IsNaughty and a list to the base class, or should I create another class called NaughtyChild that inherits from Child, and implements an ICantSitWith Interface containing a list. I'd then have to turn every Child that is Naughty into the derived class.

What I have so far

```
public class Child
{
    private static int IdCount = 0;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id{ get;  }
    public Child(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        IdCount++;
        Id = IdCount;


    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

}

public class DisruptiveChild :Child , ICantSitWith
{

    public List<Child> CantSitNextToo { get; set; }

    public DisruptiveChild(string name, List<Child> cantSitNextToo):base(name)
    {

        CantSitNextToo = cantSitNextToo;
    }

    public DisruptiveChild(string name):base(name)
    {
        CantSitNextToo = null;
    }
```

}

Comment: There's no black-and-white rules on this one, but in general I would avoid a design that requires you to throw away a `Child` object to create a `DisruptiveChild` object.  Instead, perhaps consider a design where the relationships between children are modeled as their own entities, rather than as properties of the children themselves.

Comment: Neither.  You should favor a composition approach that brings "has-a" behaviorisms to your objects instead of "is-a" inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

:)
I would go similar way as it is in reality. When you ask "Can this child sit with SomeOne?" the answer is "Yes, the child him-self can sit with AnyOne, the teacher does not want them to sit together". So it is an external need and I would not implement or incorporate it into model. I would implement it on the business level.

Unless you are modeling the classes strictly from the teacher's point of view, then of course the collection "ICantSitWith" should be a base stone on the base class ;)

Answer (score 1):

You just want to add methods to the Child class.

There are lots of reasons, but the most compelling one is that you want the user to be able to change a nice Child into a naughty Child.

You can't change an object's class after it's constructed, so you can't change a non-naughty Child instance into a NaughtyChild instance.  You could throw away the Child and create a new NaughtyChild, but that would lead to confusion and complication in an object-oriented program, where *every* reference to a thing is expected to be a reference to that thing until they're *all* thrown away.

Note that this is a **simple** concept -- an object's class determines only *immutable* characteristics of all instances of that class... just because it applies to all instances of the class and you can't change it.  Pay no attention to the fuzzy-headed intuitive reasoning in other responses.  If naughtiness is mutable then it is not determined by class in an object-oriented model.

Comment: This seems the most straight forward and the solution I'm going with,Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my openion you should prefer composition over inheritance so that later you don't end up with a complex inheritance hierarchy that will be difficult to manage. So you should be having two interfaces IChild and INaughtyChild. INaughtyChild should inherit from IChild Interface. Then you can implement the two interfaces in two separate classes where INaughtyChild implementation can use IChild implementation for common functionality.